# Mikrotik RouterOS routing between subnets on local ports

Tags: routing

Site 1: Locally connected to port 1 with interface IP 192.168.1.1/24

Site 2: Locally connected to port 2 with interface IP 192.168.2.1/24

Port 3 is the internet.

Master Ports none on all interfaces.

No firewall is configured.

Dynamic routes are listed for both subnets and the router can ping IPs on the inside of both LANs.

NAT is configured srcnat, Out-interface Port 3, masquerade, Dst. Address NOT 192.168.0.0/16

These subnets need to see each other, but cannot.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can the subnets reach the internet ?

Comment: Yes both subnets see the Internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fault was with the DHCP server setup on the Mikrotik. Before:

```
[xxxx@MikroTik] /ip dhcp-server> network print 

 # ADDRESS            GATEWAY         DNS-SERVER      WINS-SERVER     DOMAIN                 
 0 192.168.100.0/32   192.168.100.1   8.8.8.8                                       
 1 192.168.102.0/32   192.168.102.1   8.8.8.8                                        
 2 192.168.105.0/32   192.168.105.1   8.8.8.8                                       
 3 192.168.200.0/32   192.168.200.1   8.8.8.8
```

After:

```
[xxxx@MikroTik] /ip dhcp-server> network print

 # ADDRESS            GATEWAY         DNS-SERVER      WINS-SERVER     DOMAIN
 0 192.168.100.0/24   192.168.100.1   8.8.8.8                                           
 1 192.168.102.0/24   192.168.102.1   8.8.8.8                                       
 2 192.168.105.0/24   192.168.105.1   8.8.8.8                                            
 3 192.168.200.0/24   192.168.200.1   8.8.8.8
```

The difference is the subnet mask (`/32` -> `/24`).

Even though the Mikrotik has an option to add the Netmask as `/24` on the DHCP Network screen in Winbox, it does not automatically pull that mask value through to the address value and thus needs to be explicitly added to the address value as well.

(I know this export example is not exactly like my question, but I did not want to over-complicate the question)

Answer (score 0):

Site 1 and Site 2, whatever devices you have there, must have routes to point to each other, or just create a default route. The problem is that they do not know where the other is. Assuming all configs are correct.

Comment: Port 1's IP is the gateway for that LAN, and the same with the Port 2 LAN.